# The curtime minute function in MySQL doesn't work as I'd expect

Tags: mysql

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curtime(), interval 10 minute ), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S'),DATE_FORMAT(curtime(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S');
```

output is :

```
2019-07-23 10:53:44
2019-07-23 11:03:44
```

I used the same way with the 'between' and 'and'; however its giving “0 rows found”.

```
created_at between DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curtime(), interval 10 minute ), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S') 
and DATE_FORMAT(curtime(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S');
```

Comment: Why the `date_format()`? What type is `created_at` of? Hopefully not `varchar`...

Comment: I tried without date_format however it was not working . So added date_format.

created_at - type is datetime(6)

Comment: For a `datetime` leave the `date_format()` away. It's needlessly casted back anyways. Now if that doesn't find any records you most likely have no records that match. Please double check. If you believe this is not the cause then edit your question and post sample data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi Sticky bit, 
thanks for responding. My apologies!! It is working fine. it looks the DB was 1 hr behind the current time.